# My bot not reponse back after setup my webhook?

Tags: debugging, flask, heroku, python-telegram-bot

I was stuck for a day The bot isn't response back my command `/start` after setup web hook.

I swear it working fine on local with polling method. But not working after setup web hook . I'm using flask + heroku

This is my full code:

https://pastebin.com/zBesJBjb

Info : Window 10 Pro x64,
Python 3.8,
PythonTelegram Bot = 13.4.1

My WebhookInfo response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "url": "https://hello-world.herokuapp.com/xxxx",
    "has_custom_certificate": false,
    "pending_update_count": 0,
    "max_connections": 40,
    "ip_address": "54.165.0.49"
  }
}
```

My log after deploy to heroku:
https://pastebin.com/sFD403LU

Answer (score 0):

IISC, you don't process the incoming updates anywhere in `webhook_handler`. You'll have to either call `dispatcher.process_update(update)` or put the update in the dispatchers `update_queue` if you use `dispatcher.start()` in order to have the update processed. Also two more notes:

- `telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), updater)` should be changed to `telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), updater.bot)`
- if you don't use the `updater` for fetching updates, you don't need it at all, you just need a `Dispatcher`

I recommend to have a look at PTBs wiki page about [webhooks](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks). There even is a dedicated [section on Heroku](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#heroku). Admittedly, it uses `updater.start_webhook`, but I didn't really see anything in your code that explains why you're using flask instead of the built-in solution.